# Make divs properly responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a simple webpage where the artwork of an album has the tracklist beside it, the problem is that it's not very responsive and doesn't really work on mobile. The desktop version is fine, what i have in mind tho, is that on mobile, the artwork would have the tracklist under it.

help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true. For example, if the browser window is 600px or smaller, the background color will be lightblue:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Here is a [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)